# Nodejs webserver use script port 3000

Tags: javascript, node.js, scripting, webserver

I created a script in nodejs that extract data from database and create a file with all db data. I create also a webserver node js listening on port 3000 and with forever is working in listening mode all time. But now the script is without web interface and use a command line prompt and other modules. How remote users can use a remote script like : **node scrip.js** like a command shell prompt on locale machine ?

This code working but in-globe only hello world not my prompt command and db retrieve info. Thanks

```
var app = connect().use(connect.static('public')).listen(3000, "0.0.0.0");
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
 res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I understand what you are asking. But if you are just asking how to communicate with a local server running on port 3000.

Then if this is a GET request, you could simply type 'http://localhost:3000/' in a browser, or you could use a tool like [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), I recommend the [Chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog).

Comment: This script is available on local machine with node script.js and use command prompt and database functions, but how can use it remotely without web interface ?

Answer (score 0):

Local server is listening on port 3000, but i can see only hello world. But when one user access to my url http://ip:3000/ needs to use a command shell like >
**node script.js**   because i have different operations db retrieve information and input user data from command line input.